# Code insight unavailable (script configuration wasn't received) Error

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

So, I have a Kotlin-Gradle Spring Boot project. The problem is that when I open the build.gradle.kts, I get a notification stating as in the title "code insight unavailable (script configuration wasn't received error)". [image]

I tried to invalidate the cache, the proposed solution "Add to standalone scripts" did not helped. I expect that, obviously, those red lines disappear.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-26855

Answer (score 3):

According to below its a kotlin plugin issue
they planing for a fix
Note: gradle groovy will work fine

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-26855

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The problem was that the name of the module had used capitalized letters.
example:

in the **settings.gradle.kts** was:

```
include(":DATA")
```

it should have been:

```
include(":data")
```

---

In the **build.gradle.kts**:

```
implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":DATA")))
```

it should have been:

```
implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":data")))
```